# ElasticSearch Code with elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client is not getting deployed in embedded Jetty 8

Tags: elasticsearch, guava, guice, embedded-jetty, jetty-8

We are using ElasticSearch 6.8.2. Our application is written on Java. Previously we are using `transport` Client. It was working fine. But now we are upgrading to `elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client`. But after changing the code and removing all the compilation issues getting the following issue while deploying in embedded Jetty

```
com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 19744
    at com.google.inject.internal.util.$MapMaker$StrategyImpl.compute(MapMaker.java:553)
    at com.google.inject.internal.util.$MapMaker$StrategyImpl.compute(MapMaker.java:419)
    at com.google.inject.internal.util.$CustomConcurrentHashMap$ComputingImpl.get(CustomConcurrentHashMap.java:2041)
    at com.google.inject.internal.util.$StackTraceElements.forMember(StackTraceElements.java:53)
    at com.google.inject.internal.Errors.formatInjectionPoint(Errors.java:712)
    at com.google.inject.internal.Errors.formatSource(Errors.java:684)
    at com.google.inject.internal.Errors.format(Errors.java:555)
    at com.google.inject.CreationException.getMessage(CreationException.java:48)
    at java.lang.Throwable.getLocalizedMessage(Throwable.java:391)
    at java.lang.Throwable.toString(Throwable.java:480)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.setFailed(AbstractLifeCycle.java:204)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:768)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:265)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1242)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:717)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:494)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:282)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at omaelisa.core.infrastructure.test.jetty.Jetty.start(Jetty.java:119)
    at omaelisa.core.infrastructure.test.jetty.StartApplication.start(StartApplication.java:78)
    at omaelisa.core.infrastructure.test.jetty.StartApplication.start(StartApplication.java:67)
    at omaelisa.ui.ya.CorporateApplicationStarter.main(CorporateApplicationStarter.java:24)
    at omaelisa.ui.ya.StartYa$StartYaWithTestContext.main(StartYa.java:177)
    at omaelisa.ui.ya.StartYa$StartYaWithTestContextWithPet3.main(StartYa.java:60)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 19744
    at com.google.inject.internal.asm.$ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.inject.internal.asm.$ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.inject.internal.asm.$ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.inject.internal.util.$LineNumbers.<init>(LineNumbers.java:62)
    at com.google.inject.internal.util.$StackTraceElements$1.apply(StackTraceElements.java:36)
    at com.google.inject.internal.util.$StackTraceElements$1.apply(StackTraceElements.java:33)
    at com.google.inject.internal.util.$MapMaker$StrategyImpl.compute(MapMaker.java:549)
    ... 28 more
```

We are using google guava 3.0.
Please let me know how to resolve it.

Comment: Do you happen to have a minimal, reproducible example for us to look at? (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). If not, then in my experience, I find that creating one more allows me to more easily pinpoint what's going wrong. :)

Comment: As a side note, it looks like the version of Guava you're using is ancient by today's standards - it was released in 2010! By comparison, the current version is "28.1-jre".

Answer (score 0):

> [Eclipse Jetty 8 is EOL (End of Life)](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/what-jetty-version.html).
>
> Upgrade ASAP, as [you are vulnerable to many things](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/security-reports.html).

You have too old of a ASM jar.

```
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 19744
    at com.google.inject.internal.asm.$ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.inject.internal.asm.$ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.inject.internal.asm.$ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
```

See prior answer for details https://stackoverflow.com/a/26496604/775715

Comment: Yes I know. It is a legacy application so updating embedded Jetty to version 9 is a huge task. Any other solution will be very much helpful. Although while deploying in server we are using Jetty 9.3. Our Google Guice Version is 3.0.

Comment: we are using asm version 5.0.4 which is compatible with Java 8 as per the referred post.

Comment: You misunderstood, ASM version you choose needs to support the bytecode of your project and all of it's dependencies, not the runtime JVM you are running your project on.  The error you have is due to having too old of an ASM JAR for your dependencies.

Comment: In today's world, you have [Multi-Release JAR Files (JEP-238)](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/238) which are jar files that can have higher bytecode then your runtime JVM.  Check *all* of your dependencies for `META-INF/versions/` directory, those dependencies are Multi-Release JAR files.  ([Only supported on Jetty 9.4.9 and newer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50970415/775715))