# org.eclipse.jetty.util.MultiException when starting GWT Application in Eclipse SuperDevMode

Tags: eclipse, gwt, jetty

I am facing the following exception when i try to start my GWT Application within Eclipse (same for legacy Devmode and SuperDevmode).
I tried it with the newest Eclipse Version (2020-06) and also with  Eclipse Photon.
Seems like a problem with the Eclipse-Embedded Jetty-Version but the newest Eclipse (2020-06) should include a Jetty Version that supports JEP-238 Multi-Release Jars.

java Vesion 1.8

GWT Version 2.8.2

Has somebody any idea what i am doing wrong?

```
org.eclipse.jetty.util.MultiException: Multiple exceptions
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration.scanForAnnotations(AnnotationConfiguration.java:536) ~[gwt-dev.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration.configure(AnnotationConfiguration.java:447) ~[gwt-dev.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.configure(WebAppContext.java:479) ~[gwt-dev.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1337) ~[gwt-dev.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:741) ~[gwt-dev.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:505) ~[gwt-dev.jar:na]
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.jetty.JettyLauncher$WebAppContextWithReload.doStart(JettyLauncher.java:550) [gwt-dev.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68) [gwt-dev.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132) [gwt-dev.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114) [gwt-dev.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61) [gwt-dev.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.RequestLogHandler.doStart(RequestLogHandler.java:140) [gwt-dev.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68) [gwt-dev.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132) [gwt-dev.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:387) [gwt-dev.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114) [gwt-dev.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61) [gwt-dev.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:354) [gwt-dev.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68) [gwt-dev.jar:na]
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.jetty.JettyLauncher.start(JettyLauncher.java:760) [gwt-dev.jar:na]
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.doStartUpServer(DevMode.java:636) [gwt-dev.jar:na]
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.startUp(DevModeBase.java:923) [gwt-dev.jar:na]
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.run(DevModeBase.java:706) [gwt-dev.jar:na]
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.main(DevMode.java:432) [gwt-dev.jar:na]
org.eclipse.jetty.util.MultiException: Multiple exceptions
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseJar(AnnotationParser.java:899) ~[gwt-dev.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parse(AnnotationParser.java:831) ~[gwt-dev.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration$ParserTask.call(AnnotationConfiguration.java:163) ~[gwt-dev.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration$1.run(AnnotationConfiguration.java:548) ~[gwt-dev.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635) ~[gwt-dev.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555) ~[gwt-dev.jar:na]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error scanning entry META-INF/versions/9/javax/xml/bind/ModuleUtil.class from jar file:/C:/local/ws/new/web/internal/internal-war/target/webtest/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-api-2.3.1.jar
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseJar(AnnotationParser.java:913) ~[gwt-dev.jar:na]
    ... 6 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: null
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[gwt-dev.jar:na]
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[gwt-dev.jar:na]
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[gwt-dev.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.scanClass(AnnotationParser.java:973) ~[gwt-dev.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseJarEntry(AnnotationParser.java:956) ~[gwt-dev.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseJar(AnnotationParser.java:909) ~[gwt-dev.jar:na]
```

Answer (score 2):

The version of Jetty you have in your gwt is incompatible with JEP-238 (MultiRelease) jar files.

Specifically this one ...

> Error scanning entry META-INF/versions/9/javax/xml/bind/ModuleUtil.class from jar file:/C:/local/ws/new/web/internal/internal-war/target/webtest/**WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-api-2.3.1.jar**

You need to be using a gwt that has Jetty 9.4.9 or newer to support JEP-238 jar files.

[Bytecode Scanning error on META-INF/versions/9/* and Elasticsearch 6.2.2+ with Jetty 9.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50956562/bytecode-scanning-error-on-meta-inf-versions-9-and-elasticsearch-6-2-2-with-j)